# What is the difference between `npm version prerelease` and `npm version prepatch`?

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

I don't see any difference.

`npm version`:

- `prepatch`: 1.5.3 > 1.5.4-rc.0
- `preminor`: 1.5.3 > 1.6.0-rc.0
- `premajor`: 1.5.3 > 2.0.0-rc.0
- `prerelease`: 1.5.3 > 1.5.4-rc.0

i.e. `prepatch` and `prerelease` make the same. Are there cases when they don't?

Comment: [_"If the input is a non-prerelease version, \[prerelease\] acts the same as prepatch."_](https://github.com/npm/node-semver/blob/8f11f7ccff471b33da701c5a307300bacee64c1d/classes/semver.js#L201-L202) That also tells you when it _would_ be different, e.g. from `1.5.4-rc.0`, `prepatch` -> `1.5.5-rc.0` whereas `prerelease` -> `1.5.4-rc.1`.